# Bootstrap datepicker orientation/placement

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a text field with an attached datepicker placed at the bottom of the page. My problem is that the datepicker appears below the text field.

[image: Datepick]

Consequently, it appears outside the window. I Googled and found that apparently I can fix this with some `orientation` property:

```
$('#dp2').datepicker({
     orientation: 'auto top'
});
```

but this had no effect. Anyone have an idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html

Comment: Check this post for the answer.. horizontal and vertical should be used as parameters of the widgetPositioning option https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547737/bootstrap-3-datetimepicker-widget-position

Comment: If you want only top placement, remove the auto and use orientation: 'top' within the options object

Answer (score 40, accepted):

After some struggle found the required solution [image]

at [Datepicker Link](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=en&orientation=bottom%20auto&autoclose=on&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox),  just click the **Download Development** and get latest JS which include the orientation options. In the JS given defaults are:

```
var defaults = $.fn.datepicker.defaults = {
    autoclose: true,
    beforeShowDay: $.noop,
    calendarWeeks: false,
    clearBtn: false,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [],
    endDate: Infinity,
    forceParse: true,
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    keyboardNavigation: true,
    language: 'en',
    minViewMode: 0,
    orientation: "auto",
    rtl: false,
    startDate: -Infinity,
    startView: 2,
    todayBtn: false,
    todayHighlight: false,
    weekStart: 0
};
```

I just use the default :

```
orientation: "auto",
```

there are more options available for orientation.