# Bootstrap 3 datetimepicker widget position

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap 3 diatomite picker widget, but I am unable to control its position. Right now the widget appears at the bottom of my page when I don't use horizontal and vertical options, but when I use horizontal and vertical options I get an error saying horizontal is not a valid option.

These options are not working for me:
    
    **horizontal: 'right',**
    
    vertical: 'top'

Here is my code:

```
enter code here
<input type="text" value="<fmt:formatDate value="${visitDetail.visitDate }" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm aaa" />" name="patient.visitDetails[${status.index}].visitDate" class="form-control" id="visitDate${status.index}" placeholder="visitDate${status.index}"> 


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#visitDate${status.index}").datetimepicker({
            showTodayButton: true,
            inline: false,
            format: "DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm A",
            sideBySide: true,
            horizontal: 'right',
            vertical: 'top'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('.date').datetimepicker({
    language: 'es',
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoclose: 1,
    weekStart: 1,
    startView: 2,
    todayBtn: 1,
    todayHighlight: 1,
    forceParse: 0,
    minView: 2,
    pickerPosition: "top-left"
});
```

Comment: I tried normal widget positioning.. but it just wouldn't work.. This solution of `pickerPosition: "top-left"` seemed to work for me

Answer (score 26):

`horizontal` and `vertical` should be used as parameters of the `widgetPositioning` option. See http://jsfiddle.net/spasticdonkey/qmauopp0/3/

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        showTodayButton: true,
        format: "DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm A",
        sideBySide: true,
        widgetPositioning: {
            horizontal: 'right',
            vertical: 'top'
        }
    });
});
```