# Bootstrap datepicker is not aligning on hidden input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am trying inline bootstrap datepicker on div tag, whenever I click on div tag, datepicker popup is displaying on start of page(left=0, top=0)[image]

Div click is on todays date, I want to get the date and change the todays date text.

```
  <input type="hidden" id="datepicker" 
     data-provide='datepicker' 
     data-date-container='#todaysDate'>

<div id="todaysDate" class="trigger" 
   style="text-align: center; padding-top: 10px;
      font-weight: bold; color: #f58125; font-size: 16px;">
```

and also I have tried with below code also

```
form class="form-date" role="form">
        <div class="form-group" id="datepickid">
    <div id="todaysDate" class="trigger"style="text-align: center;
       padding-top: 10px; font-weight: bold; color: #f58125; 
      font-size: 16px;">
            </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="dt_due" id="datepicker">
 </div>
</form>
```

Jquery code

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){

        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            startDate: '01/01/1900',
            endDate: '12/30/2099',
            ignoreReadonly: true
        }).on('changeDate', function(ev){ 
            $('#todaysDate').text(ev.format('dd-mm-yyyy'));
            $("#datepicker").datepicker('hide'); 
        });  

         $("#datepicker").datepicker("show"); 
  });
```

both have the same problem.

whats wrong with code?
Please anybody help me

Comment: Please share the live link/demo as it is related to html structure.. Thank you

Comment: What is the point ? Why do you want to attach it for `hidden` input..

Comment: @Leothelionpls check this fidle http://jsfiddle.net/gZt3r/    I

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20265818/4719761

Comment: @RayonDabre Sir, what is the point?? Actually I need to attach it to todaysdate div, once I click it on div then datepicker popup should point to particular div right?? But its pointing on top of the page

Comment: @Developer107 Sir, I have checked that link, and changed orientation also BUT nothing is working

Comment: Make sure the parent of the datepicker has `position: relative` - that's what it attaches to, on a hidden element tho I'm not so sure but try it

Comment: @DarrenSweeneyYes I have tried with positions.. but no luck sir.. still same problem..

Comment: You can set desired style properties using `beforeShow` callback. Refer this demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/gZt3r/13/

Comment: @Developer107   tried but still the same problem :-(

Comment: @user3107283 if you hide a element it has no spac eon the DOM and you are applying plugin to this hidden element. and the datepicker will open where ever this element is.. since the element has no place in the DOM the plugin will default the position of the picker to top 0 left 0..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments. You are `Hiding` the input element in the UI, So now it does not have any space on the UI, And you are applying the date-picker plugin to this hidden input element. The plugin applies fine, But the internal logic of the plugin is to open up the date picker right at the position where the element is placed in the UI, But the problem is your element does not have any position in the UI, So the plugin defaults the position of the picker to be `top:0` and `left:0`

**Solution:** Instead of having `type="hidden"` you can use `style="visibility:hidden"`. This will make sure the element occupies some space on the UI and then the picker will also open at this position.

[**Working Fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/gZt3r/16/)

Your input should be like below.

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" style="visibility:hidden">
```

Comment: working like a charm.. Thanks Reddy garu.. Nice point out BUT in the bootstrap inline example they have mentioned text="hidden" only and one more thing, shall we update selected date to div text ?? on changeDate event like this  $('#todaysDate').text(ev.format('dd-mm-yyyy'));

Comment: got working and got date value with this $('#datepicker').val() and asigned with div  $('#todaysDate').text( $('#datepicker').val());

Comment: @user3107283 oh nice!! And glad I could help you :)

Comment: its hidden but its taking up space on the UI

Comment: nvm, its just with the styles in my css class that makes those space. Thank you!